# Perl: subroutine throwing error with $i

Tags: perl

Good morning, 
I'm having trouble using a subroutine - if I put certain code into the subroutine, it throws an error of "use of uninitialised value $i in array element".

I have a very long script, so I will only post the bit I believe is relevant.

The subroutine I am calling is commented out underneath &exon_positive_strand (saves you scrolling down). When I remove the subroutine and uncomment the code, I get no errors. I can only imagine it is something to do with $i but I don't know what...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks,
Ellie

```
my ($value, $col, $col2, $l_o_b, $left, $matchedID, $diff_three_prime, $diff_five_prime, $sequence, @three_prime_ss, @five_prime_ss, @reverse_five, @reverse_three);
my $i = 0;
open (EXONS_five, '>fasta_exons_five_non');
open (EXONS_three, '>fasta_exons_three_non');
foreach my $match(@exonic_matches) { ## works out exon from boundary relative to correct strand direction ##

if ($exon_ID[$i] !~ m/unknown/ && $dupmatches[$i] == 0)
{

$sequence = '';
$value = $exon_ID[$i];
$col = $exon_left{$value};
$col2 = $exon_right{$value};
@three_prime_ss = split(",", $col); ##splits left column into subcolumns 
@five_prime_ss = split(",", $col2); ## splits right columnn into subcolumns
@reverse_three = reverse(@three_prime_ss);
@reverse_five = reverse(@five_prime_ss);
shift(@reverse_five);

if ($strands{$value} =~ m/\+/) {

&exon_positive_strand;

# $diff_three_prime = $LBP[$i] - $three_prime_ss[$exons2{$value} - 1]; ## minus numbers denote a difference to the left (i.e. upsteam)
# $diff_five_prime = $LBP[$i] - $five_prime_ss[$exons2{$value} - 1]; ## minus numbers denote a difference to the left (i.e. upsteam)
# $matchedID = $ID{$LBP[$i]};

# if ($diff_three_prime !~ m/\-/ && $diff_three_prime <= 3) {

# $BP{$LBP[$i]} =~ s/\[[ACTG]\]/$ref[$i]/i; ## putting variant into 50BP seq

# $l_o_b = 20;
# ##$right_of_boundary = 3;

        # $l_o_b = $l_o_b + $diff_three_prime; 

        # $left = 51 - $l_o_b; 

# $sequence = substr($BP{$LBP[$i]}, $left, 23);
# }

# elsif ($diff_five_prime =~ m/\-/ && $diff_five_prime >= -3) {

# $BP{$LBP[$i]} =~ s/\[[ACTG]\]/$ref[$i]/i; ## putting variant into 50BP seq

# $l_o_b = 3;
# ##$right_of_boundary = 6;

        # $l_o_b = $l_o_b + $diff_five_prime; 

        # $left = 51 - $l_o_b; 

# $sequence = substr( $BP{$LBP[$i]}, $left, 9);
    }
 }

my $seq_length = length($sequence);

if ($seq_length == 9) {

print EXONS_five (">" . "$match_exon{$col_exon_no[$i]}" . "\n", lc($sequence),"\n");    
}
    elsif ($seq_length == 23) {
print EXONS_three (">" . "$match_exon{$col_exon_no[$i]}" . "\n", lc($sequence),"\n");
}
$i++;
}
close (EXONS_five);
close (EXONS_three);
```

Comment: It does! It's just at the bottom of my script (not shown). What is in the subroutine is the bit that is commented out.

Comment: If you want people to help you, then you need to give them as much information as possible. Rather than a hastily hacked-up version of your code, it would be great to have a short, runnable example that we can look at. There are very many array lookups that use $i in your code. Could you at least tell us which one generates the warning?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My program is 400 lines long with lots of subroutines, for, and if loops. It relies on multiple data sets that are 44,000 lines long. I am sure people would not appreciate me having had posted the entire thing. I put a lot of thought into what I would post to make it easier to follow. 

In answer to your question, perl seems to identify the LBP[$i] as the offender. If I remove the subroutine and print $LBP{$i] it prints @LBP as expected, if in subroutine it prints same value. $i works for all other variables in the subroutine so no idea why this one does not.

Comment: "I am sure people would not appreciate me having had posted the entire thing." No, they wouldn't :-) That's why I asked for "a short, runnable example". There's another benefit to doing that. In the process of stripping out all of the unnecessary stuff in order to present a short example, you'll often find that you work out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `$i` variable to the subroutine:

```
exon_positive_strand($i);
```

and

```
sub exon_positive_strand {
    my $i = shift;
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! I really appreciate your time. Would you happen to know why, in another subroutine that uses $i, I do not need to pass the $i variable to the subroutine? Seems a bit counter-intuitive for it to require passing in some occasions and not others?! Best wishes, Ellie

Comment: Without viewing your code, I can't say. But you should `use strict; use warnings;` in every script. Apart of that, glad it helps, feel free to accept the answer by checking the tick.

Comment: Any variable that you use within a subroutine should either be passed into the subroutine as a parameter, or defined inside the subroutine. That's just good software engineering practice.

Answer (score 2):

"Use of uninitialized value in array element" is not an error, it's a warning. [Diagnostics](http://p3rl.org/diagnostics) can tell you what it means:

> (W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already
>       defined.  It was interpreted as a "" or a 0, but maybe it was a mistake.
>       To suppress this warning assign a defined value to your variables.
>
> To help you figure out what was undefined, perl will try to tell you the
>       name of the variable (if any) that was undefined. In some cases it cannot
>       do this, so it also tells you what operation you used the undefined value
>       in.  Note, however, that perl optimizes your program and the operation
>       displayed in the warning may not necessarily appear literally in your
>       program.  For example, "that $foo" is usually optimized into "that "
>       . $foo, and the warning will refer to the concatenation (.) operator,
>       even though there is no . in your program.